# opencv - canny edge detection with adaptive threshold parameter for video(java)

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to use canny edge detection on each frame in a video. I can use it no problem but because each image is different the threshold parameters in the canny method will need to be custom to that image.

I have got good advice on here about calculating the median and then using .33 percentile above and below that for high and low threshold parameters in the canny method.

something like

```
        Imgproc.Canny(gray, fullCanny, thirdAboveMedian, thirdBelowMedian);
```

So I have tried calculating the median and the percentiles and plugging them in but my calculations must be wrong somewhere as I am only getting a black screen with these values??

here is the code i used to work it out.

```
Mat fullCanny = new Mat();


            fullCanny=gray.clone();
            fullCanny.reshape(0,1);
            double median;
            double thirdAboveMedian;
            double thirdBelowMedian;
             int[] histogram = hist(fullCanny);
             if(histogram.length%2==0)
             {
                median = (histogram[histogram.length/2] + histogram[histogram.length/2 - 1 ])/2;
                thirdAboveMedian = histogram[(histogram.length/2)+(histogram.length/2/3)];
                thirdBelowMedian = histogram[(histogram.length/2)-(histogram.length/2/3)];

             }
             else
             {
                median = histogram[(int)histogram.length/2];
                thirdAboveMedian = histogram[(int)(histogram.length/2)+(histogram.length/2/3)];
                thirdBelowMedian = histogram[(histogram.length/2)-(histogram.length/2/3)];

             }
             System.out.println("median is "+median);
             System.out.println("thirdAboveMedian is "+thirdAboveMedian);
             System.out.println("thirdBelowMedian is "+thirdBelowMedian);


            //run edge detection on the blurred gray image and display it on fullCanny mat
            Imgproc.Canny(gray, fullCanny, thirdAboveMedian, thirdBelowMedian);
```

And the hist method

public static int[] hist(Mat img) {

```
// array for intensities
int hist[] = new int[256];
byte data[] = new byte[img.rows() * img.cols() * img.channels()];
img.get(0, 0, data);

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    hist[(data[i] & 0xff)]++;
}
return hist;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: the best method hands down, is to find the median(of gray scale) for each frame and set 0.33 percentile above and below the median as the lower and upper threshold

Comment: Yes I have read this but I can't find a java method to return the median, do i need to write a method and work it out from the image histogram? the only median filtering I can see online is about blurring??

Comment: I have no idea how to go about doing the same in Java

Comment: Is there a method to find the median is C or whatever language you use? or do you work out the median yourself?

Comment: I used the `numpy` library available in python... :D

Comment: [Google it](http://answers.opencv.org/question/20522/get-the-median-added-to-mean-and-std-value/)

Comment: @RickM. I have been on google all day it seems there isn't too many resources for using openCv with java

Comment: I am going to edit the question to see if someone can help find the median of an image in java

Comment: Can't you change the C++ code to java? And btw, the link I added is in android

Comment: It is just hard when I have never used C++ before

Comment: From the top of my head,(if you don't have huge images), [reshape the image](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#reshape(int)) to a single row. [Sort it](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7108). Check if the number of elements is even/odd. Get the median

Comment: OK I think I have done that and found the median. now I just need to know what is meant by 0.33 percentile above and below the median. Is that 1/3 between half way and the end of the array?

Comment: @MickO'Gorman Yes Exactly!!

Comment: Glad that helped! I didn't mean to be rude with the 'Google it' comment. Do you want me to add this as an answer so it can help others? If you did it, then you should add an answer yourself

Comment: @RickM. Let him write the answer himself. We can upvote it    :D

Comment: No probem with the Google comment. Not there though yet lads having trouble calculating the percentiles lol.

Comment: I have edited the question, can either of you see where I am going wrong?

Comment: What are the outputs of the System? I don't think the hist function is doing what is intended. Additionally, `fullCanny.reshape(0,1);` doesn't change the mat fullCanny, it returns the reshaped Mat. You might want to write `int[] histogram = hist(fullCanny.reshape(0, 1));`

Comment: Wait am i meant to be using ratios of the median? because           Imgproc.Canny(gray, fullCanny,1.33*median, 0.66*median);  doesnt look too bad?

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: No that didnt fix it, the values are like thirdAboveMedian is 13.0
thirdBelowMedian is 972.0
median is 42.0
thirdAboveMedian is 12.0
thirdBelowMedian is 992.0
median is 56.0
thirdAboveMedian is 13.0
thirdBelowMedian is 889.0

Comment: I don't think you are sorting the array. And, 972/889 don't look correct for a gray scale image.

Comment: @JeruLuke looks like he hasn't found the solution yet!

Comment: @RickM.  OMG!!! Are you still keeping track of this??

Comment: @JeruLuke just curious! Probably I am more concerned than the OP!

Comment: The median thing didn't work for me, tried loads of things. Eventually i wrote  out otsu's method myself to see if it would help but it didn't look great. It was some what adaptive though. I then multiplied my result by 3 because higher threshold was seeming to work a lot better and it was still adaptive to each frame of the video. But kind of random in a way.  I never found any method to do this automatically in java though. It was for an assignment so i probably won't be coming back to it. Appreciated the help though thanks